# Online text layout with margin annotations and margin images

Tags: html, cms, css

I'm intending to post some texts, on a website of my own design. I intend to display these texts continuously, like blog posts. In the margins of the page, I'd like to have notes and images that are directly linked to specific sentences and words in the texts. I'm imagining it would look something like the comments feature in Word 2010, or the layout of PubMed Central (PMC), wherein in-text references are displayed as article titles on the right hand ([see example here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3048376/)).

Does there exist some web application/software that could do this for me, without having to code it from the ground up?